# How to avoid truncate text in select box in extjs

Tags: extjs

I have combo box in extjs with minWidth set. when i select longest string from the select list. string get truncated in text field of combo box. how to avoid truncation of string to view full string which we have selected from the list.

Comment: Please describe more of what you have done so far; your HTML and JS would clearly be more helpful in solving the issue. 
As for the problem, you could use a tooltip to show the truncated value as an alternative.

Comment: i have select box and the store i populate from the server. due to padding of x-form-text my last chartacter from the selected string get truncated. i want to avoid the truncation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the box wider. Ext won't do that automatically. The minWidth of form fields is for cases where the panel/container around it can be resized and the form field has `flex` set, but out of the box, a form field will never resize based on the content of the field.

If you still want your to resize your field with the content, you can look [here](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.util.TextMetrics) for an approach how to implement that manually.

Comment: used Ext.util.TextMetrics to measure the width of longest string in my list after populating combobox store and then depending of width measured, changed the width of combo box. Thanks Alexander.

Answer (score 0):

Use listConfig configuartion in combo and apply required css to remove truncate. Please go through my example.

```
.withOutTruncate{
    word-wrap: break-word; 
}

`var states = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    fields: ['abbr', 'name'],
    data: [{
        "abbr": 'largeText',
        "name": 'testtesttesttesttestetsetetetetetetetetehjghh'
    }, {
        "abbr": "AL",
        "name": "Alabama"
    }, {
        "abbr": "AK",
        "name": "Alaska"
    }, {
        "abbr": "AZ",
        "name": "Arizona"
    }]
});

Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox', {
    fieldLabel: 'Choose State',
    store: states,
    listConfig: {
        cls: 'withOutTruncate'
    },
    queryMode: 'local',
    valueField: 'abbr',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    displayField: 'name'
});
```

Note: I am not good in css. I tried with word-break it is working fine at my end but you apply text properties css to make it work much better.